# Sustainsys.saml2: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience

Tags: webforms, single-sign-on, identity, sustainsys-saml2

I am implementing sustainsys.saml2, working with Framework 4.7.2, to connect to a identity provider in Azure Ad.

Sustainsys.Saml2-2.9.2
Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule-2.9.2

Is there any configuration parameter in web.config to fix the error I am getting:

"IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'spn:XXXXXXX'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'XXXXXXX' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'."

[SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'spn:b2314dc9-bb7d-4797-bc1f-0767fa073c20'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'b2314dc9-bb7d-4797-bc1f-0767fa073c20' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.]
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) +723 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateConditions(Saml2SecurityToken samlToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) +369 Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P.Saml2PSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken) +57 Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P.<CreateClaims>d__66.MoveNext() +785 System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +453 System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +69
Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P.Saml2Response.GetClaims(IOptions options, IDictionary`2 relayData) +242
Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.AcsCommand.ProcessResponse(IOptions options, Saml2Response samlResponse, StoredRequestState storedRequestState, IdentityProvider identityProvider, String relayState) +98
Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.AcsCommand.Run(HttpRequestData request, IOptions options) +968
Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule.Saml2AuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +407
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +223
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +220
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +94

Thank you

I have tried to include several parameters, for instance:

```
`    <system.identityModel.services>
        <federationConfiguration>
            <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
       </federationConfiguration>
    </system.identityModel.services>  
`
```

Also, including in Global.asax - Application_BeginRequest:

```
`    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;`
```

I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "feature" of Microsoft Entra ID. The SAML2 spec requires the audience to be an absolute URI. If the configured value isn't a URI, Entra ID "fixes" that [by appending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/single-sign-on-saml-protocol#audience) `spn:`.

Best way to solve it is to change the SP Entity ID to be an absolute URI.